# Find a non-linear function that when composed with a distance function is also a distance function.

Tags: functions, inequality, metric-spaces

Is there a non-linear function from $\mathbb{R}^+_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+_0$ so that for each distance function $d$ (on any set), the composition $f◦d$ is also a distance function?

I know that for $f◦d$ to be a distance function it must satisfy:

Let $X$ be a set and let $d : X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+_0$. For $d$ to be a distance function it must satisfy the following conditions $\forall x, y, z \in X$

1. $d(x, y) \geq 0$
2. $d(x, y) = 0 \iff x = y$
3. $d(x, y) = d(y, x)$
4. $d(x, z) \leq d(x, y) + d(y, z)$

I have tried using $f = \sqrt x$. I am sure my proof for the first 3 conditions is correct however i am not sure about condition 4.

---

My Attempt:

To prove: $\sqrt{d(x,z)} \leq \sqrt{d(x,y)} + \sqrt{d(y,z)}$.

We already know that $d$ satisfies condition 4, so square rooting both side gives me $\sqrt{d(x,z)} \leq \sqrt{d(x,y) + d(y, z)}$.

From the triangle inequality we know that $\sqrt{d(x,y)} + \sqrt{d(y,z)} \geq \sqrt{d(x,y) + d(y, z)}$

$\implies \sqrt{d(x,y)} + \sqrt{d(y,z)} \geq \sqrt{d(x,y) + d(y, z)} \geq \sqrt{d(x, z)}$.

Q.E.D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks correct to me. You might want to show why
$$\sqrt{d(x,y)}+\sqrt{d(y,z)}\geq\sqrt{d(x,y)+d(y,z)}.$$
For instance by squaring both sides.